# Are there test functions $\in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}$ which aren't in the algebra generated by $f_{a,b}(x) := e^{\frac{C}{(x-a)(x-b)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

The standard test ($\in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$) function is the following
\begin{equation*}
f_{a,b}^{(c)}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \
x \mapsto \begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{C}{(x - a)(x - b)}\right), & \text{if } a < x < b, \\
0, & \text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Where $C := \frac{c(a - b)^2}{4}$. Then, $f \in  \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$,  supp$(f) \subset [a,b]$ and $\max\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) = e^{-c}$.

> Are there fundamentally different test functions and if not, why?

I want "fundamentally different" to mean that you can't express it in the form exp of the reciprocal of a polynomial (mutiplied by a constant) for an interval $[a,b]$ and zero elsewhere.

**Edit: (response to @md2perpe's comment about convoluting with an indicator function)**
We can construct a function which is very similar to the one you described by using the function from above (*Note: this is not the exact function, but we had to this for a homework way back so I decided to post it here, it can surely be modified to be exactly your example*).

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$ define
$$
h_{\alpha, x}: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1],
t \mapsto
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } t \in [x - \frac{\alpha}{2}, x + \frac{\alpha}{2}], \\
\exp\left(1 -\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}(t + \frac{\alpha}{2} - x )\right)^2 } \right), 
& \text{if } t \in [x - \alpha, x - \frac{\alpha}{2}), \\
\exp\left(1 -\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}(t - \frac{\alpha}{2} - x )\right)^2 } \right), 
& \text{if } t \in (x + \frac{\alpha}{2}, x + \alpha], \\
0, & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Then, we have
$$
h_{\alpha, x}(t) = \begin{cases}
1, & t \in [x - \frac{\alpha}{2}, x + \frac{\alpha}{2}] \\
0, & t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [x - \alpha, x + \alpha].
\end{cases},
$$
which is fundamentally different from the function above.

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, maybe you could reformulate your question as: are there functions in $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ that are not in the algebra generated by the $f_{a,b}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{C}{(x - a)(x - b)}\right), & \text{if } a < x < b, \\
0, & \text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}$? Can we find an explicit example?

Comment: @CharlesMadeline. Under what operations do you consider that algebra be generated?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik. For example $f_{-1,1}^{(1)} * \chi_{[-10, 10]}.$

Comment: @md2perpe We have $$f_{-1,1}^{(1)} \ast \chi_{[-10,10]}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{\frac{1}{\tau^2 - 1}} \cdot 1_{[-10, 10]}(t - \tau) d \tau = \int_{t - 10}^{t + 10} e^{\frac{1}{\tau^2 - 1}} d \tau,$$ right? How does such a function look like?

Comment: @md2perpe I was thinking about addition and multiplication (as a subalgebra of $\mathcal{C}^0$). But I don't really know what 'fundamentally different' meant for Viktor

Comment: @ViktorGlombik. The result will be a function that leaves zero at -11, reaches a level at -9, stays constant on that level until +9, and then becomes zero again at +11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to construct such a test function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions).

Define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp\left(- \frac{1}{x}\right), & x > 0, \\
0, & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) =  \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}
= \begin{cases}
0, & x \le 0, \\
\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{2x - 1}{x(x-1)}\right) + 1}, & 0 < x < 1, \\
1 & x \ge 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, the function $h(x) := g\left(\frac{x - a}{b - a}\right) g\left(\frac{d - x}{d - c}\right)$ equals one on $[b,c]$ and vanished outside $(a,d)$.

Comment: All explicit constructions of $C_c^\infty$-functions are (as far as I know) based on $f$. For example, $f_{a,b}^{(c)}(x) = f((x-a)(x-b)/C).$ So maybe the question should rather be if there are $C_c^\infty$-functions that do not belong to the algebra generated of functions of the form $f \circ u$ where $u$ is ... (what should it say here?).

Answer (score 2):

> I want "fundamentally different" to mean that you can't express it in the form exp of the reciprocal of a even polynomial (mutiplied by a constant) for an interval $[a,b]$ and zero elsewhere.

With that criteria, it's easy to construct a fundamentally different example. Just square the polynomial:
\begin{equation*}
f_{a,b}^{(c)}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \
x \mapsto \begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{C}{(x - a)^2(x - b)^2}\right), & \text{if } a < x < b, \\
0, & \text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: And, even more general: $\exp\left(\frac{C \cdot (-1)^{n+1}}{(x - a)^{n} (x - b)^{n}}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks to your example I realise I wan't precise enough in my comment you quoted. One should probably get rid of the ```even``` in that sentence. The example you gave would be different in this manner as well since it's constantly 1 on an interval, which isn't true for this function or the one I stated at the beginning of my question.